# Modification to Lazy<T> singleton code

Tags: c#, .net, generics, singleton, func

Create the singleton class based on 6th version provided in Jon Skeet's book check [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

**Class - CacheSingleton**

```
public sealed class CacheSingleton<TK,TV>
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<ICache<TK,TV>> lazyIgnite =
                                                new Lazy<ICache<TK,TV>>(() =>
                                                {
                                                    NearCacheConfiguration nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfiguration { NearStartSize = 10240000 };

                                                    var nearCache = IgniteInstance.GetOrCreateNearCache<TK, TV>(SingletonCacheName,nearCacheConfig);

                                                    return nearCache;
                                                });

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private static string SingletonCacheName = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public static ICache<TK, TV> Instance(string cacheName)
        {
            SingletonCacheName = cacheName;
            return lazyIgnite.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private CacheSingleton() { }
    }
```

**Modification to the original Article:**

- `Instance` is a Method instead of property, since I need to supply the CacheName, for fetching the correct Cache

**Issues:**

- Even with current modification, I can only fetch a specific Cache instance for a combination of `Tk,TV` types, since at no place I am able to factor in `string` input except the first time, second time on-wards it will always fetch same instance even if string value if different.
- Primary reason for the issue is `Lazy` type takes `Func<T>`, there's no scope of an additional parameter.

Any pointer to factor in the string input, along with `TK,TV`

Comment: Not sure if a wrapper with `ICache<TK,TV>`  and `String` value is the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a `ConcurrentDictionary`?

```
public static class CacheSingleton<TK, TV>
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICache<TK, TV>> lazyIgnite = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICache<TK, TV>>();

    public static ICache<TK, TV> GetInstance(string cacheName)
    {
        return lazyIgnite.GetOrAdd(cacheName, name =>
        {
            NearCacheConfiguration nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfiguration { NearStartSize = 10240000 };
            var nearCache = IgniteInstance.GetOrCreateNearCache<TK, TV>(name, nearCacheConfig);
            return nearCache;
        });
    }
}
```

This is a lazy and thread-safe cache for your instances.
Perhaps you also want to implement a `Clear` method to reset the cache.

Comment: We both posted the same answer within 30 seconds of each other. :)

Comment: Nothing much to differentiate except that here you have pasted my complete code, can only select 1 answer

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use a `ConcurrentDictionary` to implement this? Something like:

```
public static class CacheSingleton<TK, TV>
{
    public static ICache<TK, TV> Instance(string cacheName)
    {
        return _cache.GetOrAdd(cacheName, create);
    }

    static ICache<TK, TV> create(string cacheName)
    {
        // Code to create an ICache<TK, TV> given cacheName.

        return null; // Stubbed.
    }

    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICache<TK, TV>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ICache<TK, TV>>();
}
```

Comment: At times, when mind is too involved in solving a specific way, as shown in the book, as I was bent upon modifying that code and its APIs, did not consider the alternate, which is so simple, thank-you very much